# Changing tenses

Tags: tenses, past-tense, past-participles

I am a sports writer and was wondering if this sentence is wrong because it starts in the past tense and changes to past participle

"Sophomore Chelsea Vujs recorded a double-double by scoring a game-high 21 points and pulling down 10 rebounds "

Answer (score 1):

No, it's fine as written because "scoring" and "pulling" are essentially set in that past "time."  Otherwise, you'd have to write "..recorded a [2-2] *when* {or maybe "as"} she scored ... and pulled down..."

There's a name for those sub-clauses but I forget it at the moment. It's not "past participle," though.